# How to change button color onClick if I have multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

If I have a single button , it is possible to change color this way ,,

```
<script>
var count = 1;
function setColor(btn, color) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;        
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

But how to do this if I have multiple buttons and multiple colors (eg: 10 buttons with 3 possible colors )

Comment: Do you want all of the 10 buttons to be the same color?

Comment: Make arrays of buttons and colors. Use for loop to cycle through them and your function to change their color.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;
function setColor(btn, color) {
    var btns = document.getElementByClass("button_class_name");
    for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
          btns.item(i).style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
    }
}
```

This will set all the buttons with the class "button_class_name" to "7FFF00".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have ten `buttons` , give a common class to all buttons .Bind events to each one of them as below.

```js
 var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("btns");
    var count =1;
    var setColor = function() {
        var button = this;
        if (count == 0) {
            button.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute("data-color");
            console.log(this.getAttribute("data-color"))
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            button.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute("data-color");
             console.log(this.getAttribute("data-color"))
            count = 0;
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', setColor, false);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" data-color="#7FFF00" value="btn1" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn2" data-color="#7FFF00" value="btn2" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn3" data-color="#FC0" value="btn3" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn4" data-color="#FFFPPP" value="btn4" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn5" data-color="#FC0" value="btn5" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn6" data-color="#7FFF00" value="btn6" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn7" data-color="#7FFF00" value="btn7" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn8" data-color="#FC0" value="btn8" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn9" data-color="#FFFPPP" value="btn9" class="btns">
    <input type="button" id="btn10" data-color="#FC0" value="btn10" class="btns">
```

If you want to give each one of them have to be different color , you can put data attributes to buttons `data-color='#FC0'` for example and assign this color as dynamically.
 If you have ***ES6 support*** you can replace your last line with:

```
Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', setColor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.`Toggle` with three `color's` for all Button's .Create the color array .Then count the num of `click's` with `data-count` of the each button element .Then Match the `count` with color array using `this.dataset.count%col.length`

```js
var count = 1;
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(a){
a.addEventListener('click', setColor)
})

var col = ["#FFFFFF","#AAAAAA","#6A76A7"];
function setColor() {
this.dataset.count= this.dataset.count >= 0 ? ++this.dataset.count : 0;
   this.style.backgroundColor = col[this.dataset.count%col.length] 
}
```

```html
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
<button>one</button><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like that.

**HMTL**

```
<button class="buttons" id="btn-1">Button1</button>
<button class="buttons" id="btn-2">Button2</button>
<button class="buttons" id="btn-3">Button3</button>
<button class="buttons" id="btn-4">Button4</button>
<button class="buttons" id="btn-5">Button5</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;

  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
// Change one button color
function setButtonColor(btn, color) {
  btn.css({'background': color});
}

// Change a set of buttons color
function setButtonsColor(btns, colors) {
  $.each(btns, function (key, value) {
    setButtonColor($(value), colors);
  });
}

$(function(){

  setButtonsColor( $('.buttons'), 'gold')

  setButtonColor( $('#btn-1'), 'red' );
  setButtonColor( $('#btn-3'), 'purple' );

   $('.buttons').click(function(){
     setButtonColor( $(this), 'lightgreen' );
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an object based approach. Makes for easy to extend functionality at a later date.

My understanding of the questions is each of the buttons will cycle through each of the colours depending on how many times the button has been clicked.

For example, 1 click = red, 2 clicks = green...

```js
// Only 3 colours and buttons for a test.
// This list of colours
var cList = ['#f00','#0f0','#00f'];
// The butExtend object will become an array here
var butList = [];

// This object keeps track of the number of button clicks.
var ButExtend = function butObj(id) {
  this.count = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(id)) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click',bClick,false);
  }
};

// Called on a button click
function bClick() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = cList[butList[this.id].count];
  butList[this.id].count++;
  if (butList[this.id].count >= cList.length) {
    butList[this.id].count = 0;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  // The list of id's for the buttons.
  var bId = ['b1','b2','b3'];
  for(x in bId) {
    butList[bId[x]] = new ButExtend(bId[x]);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="b1">but 1</button>
<button id="b2">but 2</button>
<button id="b3">but 3</button>
```